# Is it possible to pass arguments to let block during the call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

I've started to use Rspec and right now I wrote several successfully worked and pretty difficult tests. But as I need more practice I did refactor of these tests few times.

I not found an answer for my question in Rspec's documentation and that's why I here.

The question is about directive `let` that provides an ability to return some objects by first call and not only, you know.

My current part of rspec code is:

```rb
RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  describe 'profiles' do
    context 'should be visible by' do
      it 'related company managers' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in create(:manager, :company, company: company) # Pay attention on this
        get user_path(create(:member, :company, company: company)) # this
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end

      it 'related company owners' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in create(:owner, :company, company: company) # this
        get user_path(create(:member, :company, company: company)) # and this
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There are only two example of 63 that are under the User's spec, but they are enough. I want to refactor the code to use `let` which will define a method with parameters, like that:

```rb
RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  let(:member) do |entity_name = :company, entity = create(entity_name)|
    create :member, entity_name, entity_name => entity
  end
  let(:manager) do |entity_name = :company, entity = create(entity_name)|
    create :manager, entity_name, entity_name => entity
  end
  let(:owner) do |entity_name = :company, entity = create(entity_name)|
    create :owner, entity_name, entity_name => entity
  end

  describe 'profiles' do
    context 'should be visible by' do
      it 'related company managers' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in manager(:company, company) # Become more readable here
        get user_path(member(:company, company)) # here
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end

      it 'related company owners' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in owner(:company, company) # here
        get user_path(member(:company, company)) # and here.
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Right after the refactor the Guard says:

```
  1) Users profiles should be visible by related company managers
     Failure/Error: sign_in manager(:company, company) # Become more readable here

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:38:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From the `memorized_helpers.rb` of Rspec core I saw:

```rb
def let(name, &block)
  # We have to pass the block directly to `define_method` to
  # allow it to use method constructs like `super` and `return`.
  raise "#let or #subject called without a block" if block.nil?
  raise(
    "#let or #subject called with a reserved name #initialize"
  ) if :initialize == name
  MemoizedHelpers.module_for(self).__send__(:define_method, name, &block)

  # Apply the memoization. The method has been defined in an ancestor
  # module so we can use `super` here to get the value.
  if block.arity == 1
    define_method(name) { __memoized.fetch_or_store(name) { super(RSpec.current_example, &nil) } }
  else
    define_method(name) { __memoized.fetch_or_store(name) { super(&nil) } }
  end
end
```

It looks like `let`'s blocks should be defined with parameters. Or not?
I haven't enough experience to determine it and I would be glad to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've found possible solution: return a lambda and call it in place

```rb
RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  let(:member) do
    ->(entity_name = :company, entity = create(entity_name)) do
      create :member, entity_name, entity_name => entity
    end
  end
  let(:manager) do
    ->(entity_name = :company, entity = create(entity_name)) do
      create :manager, entity_name, entity_name => entity
    end
  end
  let(:owner) do
    ->(entity_name = :company, entity = create(entity_name)) do
      create :owner, entity_name, entity_name => entity
    end
  end

  describe 'profiles' do
    context 'should be visible by' do
      it 'related company managers' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in manager.(:company, company) # Pay attention on the dot here
        get user_path(member.(:company, company)) # here
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end

      it 'related company owners' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in owner.(:company, company) # here
        get user_path(member.(:company, company)) # and here.
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is not exactly that I want, but seems like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  describe 'profiles' do
    let(:request) { get user_path(user) }
    let(:user)    { create(:member, :company, company: company) }
    let(:company) { create(:company) }

    shared_examples_for 'has visibility to user' do
      before { sign_in employee }

      it do 
        request
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      end
    end

    context 'manager' do
      let(:employee) { create(:manager, company: company) }

      it_behaves_like 'has visibility to user'
    end

    context 'owner' do
      let(:employee) { create(:owner, company: company) }

      it_behaves_like 'has visibility to user'
    end
  end
end
```

Similarly, you should be able to do something like:

```
it_behaves_like 'has visibility to user' do
 let(:employee) { create(:manager, company: company) }
end
```

with [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples). I suggest checking out http://www.betterspecs.org/.

(Aside, it's confusing to have a factory named `:member` and not `:user` since the `GET` request is for `user_path`; I recommend renaming it.)

Answer (score -1):

The another solution is creation of helpers. For example, create a file in `spec/support/users_helper.rb`.

```rb
module UsersSpecHelper

  def member(entity = :company)
    create :member, *entity(entity)
  end

  def manager(entity = :company)
    create :manager, *entity(entity)
  end

  def owner(entity = :company)
    create :owner, *entity(entity)
  end

  private

    def entity(entity)
      if entity.is_a? Symbol
        [entity, entity => create(entity)]
      else
        name = entity.class.to_s.downcase.to_sym
        [name, name => entity]
      end
    end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include UsersSpecHelper, type: :request
end
```

Uncomment in `spec/rails_helper.rb` the line:

```rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

and then it can be used even better:

```rb
RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  describe 'profiles' do
    context 'should be visible by' do
      it 'managers of related company' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in manager(company) # Changes are here
        get user_path(member(company)) # here
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end

      it 'owners of related company' do
        company = create(:company)
        sign_in owner(company) # here
        get user_path(member(company)) # and here.
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```